# What is an "opening edge" in computer terms

Tags: opening, engines

When analysing with stockfish on chessbase, there are often positions reached in openings where the engine's eval is around +0.2 ish and the verdict is "position is equal". So at what computer eval can white claim a minor opening edge such as what may be produced by accurate play against an opening like Alekhine's defence or the Scandinavian.

Comment: That seems very difficult and open-ended to precisely answer. But I would suggest playing through some main lines (in the database) of openings like those you mentioned and see what the engine says the eval is.